# How to make zoom at 100% (default state) in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, zoom

I can use control + scroll to zoom in and zoom out the screen in Windows 7.
How can I make it 100%?

With MS Word, there is a indicator to show the percentage, but I don't know how to see the percentage in other applications such as IE.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the application. In browsers such as IE, Firefox, and Chrome, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>in order to reset the zoom. To zoom in, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> will work fine and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> for zooming out. The exact options will always be available under the 'View' menu, or similar.

If you are trying to change the resolution of your screen in Windows 7, this is a different story. [Here is the link to the Microsoft page that tells you how to do that](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-your-screen-resolution). Or you can just right click your desktop and go to `Screen Resolution`.

Comment: also check out the switches in Internet Options, Advanced. in there are items for making Font size and Zoom Sticky, or resetting. A favorite for me is to "Custom" edit the "toolbar" in IE and to add in the Font size, and Zoom Icons to the toolbar.  Once they are  visable, it is more intuitive to control with the mouse.

Answer (score 3):

This is an application-specific option and in Internet Explorer, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to make the zoom level 100% (default).